# Operation with double value returning 0. Can't understand why

Tags: c

I am writing a code to find the harmonic of two double values. However, I just end up getting
0.0000 as the result. Need help to resolve this.

```
/*The harmonic mean of two numbers is obtained by taking the inverses of the two
numbers, averaging them, and taking the inverse of the result. Write a function that
takes two double arguments and returns the harmonic mean of the two numbers.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
double h_mean(double i,double j);
int main(void){
    double i,j;
    double hMean = h_mean(i,j);
    printf("%1f",hMean);
    return 0;
}

double h_mean(double i,double j){
    puts("Enter 2 numbers");
    scanf("%1f %1f",&i,&j);

    double inv_num = (1/i+1/j)/2;
    double inv_result = 1/inv_num;

    return inv_result;

}
```

Comment: Look closely at your format specifiers:  `%1f` --> `%lf`.

Comment: Thanks, its working now.. I always saw that as a 1 and not an l... Thank you for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a mistake using `%1f` for getting the floats since you'll only get one digit. You probably want to use `l` (ell) rather than `1` (wun).

In addition, a function like `h_mean` should do what it says, which is work out the harmonic mean. It should *not* be getting user input, especially since the variables are passed to it from `main`. You would be better off starting with something like (with comments explaining why):

```
#include <stdio.h>

// I'm a fan of DRY, so I tend to put definintions first. That
// way, I don't have to maintain definition *and* declaration.

double h_mean(double i, double j) {
    // I like explicit doubles, like 1.0. I also like spaces :-)

    double inv_num = (1.0 / i + 1.0 / j) / 2.0;
    double inv_result = 1.0 / inv_num;
    return inv_result;
}

int main(void) {
    double i, j;
    // Main should be getting input, leaving h_mean to do one thing,
    // and one thing well.
    // Also use lf (ell) rather than 1f (wun), and check that scanf
    // worked okay.
    // And I like data entry on the prompt line.

    printf("Enter 2 numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%lf %lf", &i, &j) != 2) {
        puts("Invalid input");
        return 1;
    }
    double hMean = h_mean(i, j);

    // No need for lf in printf, that's only needed for scanf.

    printf("%f\n", hMean);

    return 0;
}
```

With that code, I get (with a sample run):

```
Enter 2 numbers: 3.14159265359 2.71828182846
2.914647
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now.. I always saw that as a 1 and not an l...Thanks

Comment: Got it.. I was just lazy to call from main..But I understand your point and will keep that in my mind in my future codes..Thanks